# Why Cardview is over Appbar?

Tags: android, layout, android-cardview, appbar

After trying many times I didn't figure out how to solve my problem. In my layout I have a navigation drawer with an appbar, inside it there's a Cardview with Relative layout. Here is a screen in my preview while coding xml in layout :

[image: preview emulator]

When i launch the app on emulator or the phone, I have this :

[image]

My Cardview appears over Appbar. Full layout code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
tools:context=".activities.display.MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#80FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newresearch_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Rechercher"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newresearch_title"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
            android:hint="Prix min"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
            android:hint="Prix max"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bouton_de_recherche"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="Rechercher"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<include
    layout="@layout/navdraw_appbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navdraw_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Thanks for the help !

EDIT: Added code of navdraw_appbar below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".activities.display.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What is your parent layout?

Comment: try inlcude app bar layout above cardview

Comment: already done, didn't work :/

Comment: why you applying this `app:cardBackgroundColor="#80FFFFFF"` to your cardview?

Comment: it's not really the purpose, but to answer, it's to make it a little transparent

Comment: Add navdraw_appbar_main xml...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
tools:context=".activities.display.MainActivity"
tools:openDrawer="">

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    layout="@layout/navdraw_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rltv_allcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#80FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/newresearch_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Rechercher"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/newresearch_title"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
            android:hint="Prix min"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_edittext"
            android:hint="Prix max"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bouton_de_recherche"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button"
            android:text="Rechercher"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
 </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/navdraw_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: It looks well on the preview, seems to work, only problem is that it's out of the screen, if I just want to see a little piece, like the title "Rechercher" , I had to put a margin bottom at 100dp

Comment: I included it after the beginning of the RelativeLayout (with id rltv_allcontent, and before cardview) and added a 70dp marginTop, it is fine now, I don't really know if it is the  best way to do it...

Comment: It's ok. you can add margin from top in rltv_allcontent or in cardview

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently. Assuming that your activity extends AppCompatActivity, have you set the toolbar in your activity?

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: thanks for you help, yes it was set already and it didn't work still